# Is the conditional distribution on $X=x$, where $X$ is continuous, always defined?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, conditional-probability

Let $X$ be a continuous real random variable, $Y \in \{0, 1\}$ be a discrete random variable and let $\mathcal D$ denote their joint probability distribution.

I've seen many times in the context of classification theory, describing the joint distribution $\mathcal D$ in terms of its $X$-marginal distribution $\mathcal D_X$ and the conditional probability $\eta(x) = \mathbb P[Y = 1 \mid X = x] = \mathbb E[Y \mid X = x]$.

My question regards whether the conditioning on $X=x$ in $\eta(x)$ poses constraints on the family of distributions $\mathcal D$ for which $\eta(x)$ is defined. Obviously, in the case where $\mathcal D_X$ has a pdf, $\eta(x)$ is well defined and can be expressed it terms of the pdf.

**Question:** For general distributions, where $X$ might not have a pdf, can $\eta(x) = \mathbb P[Y = 1 \mid X = x]$ still be defined?

Comment: How comfortable are you with measure theoretic probability? I think the formal definition of conditional expectation is needed in order to give a solid answer to this question.

Comment: I've recently started getting acquainted with measure theoretic probability. Despite not being fully familiar yet, a measure theoretic answer would be perfectly welcome.

Comment: You may want to give a look on [regular conditional probability](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_conditional_probability). This tells that a "nice and consistent" version of the family of conditional probabilities, $\mathbf{P}(\cdot\mid X=x)$, can be defined. Alternatively, for your specific question, it is sufficient to invoke a simpler fact that the conditional expectation $$\mathbf{P}(Y=1\mid X)=\mathbf{E}[\mathbf{1}_{\{Y=1\}}\mid X]$$ exists and can be written in the form $\eta(X)$ for some Borel-measurable function $\eta(x)$.